# Java - Padding an integer

Tags: java, integer, type-conversion, padding, talend

Well, I have a string in my Java code that needs to be converted into an integer with padding of 10. 
Ex. Consider this is the string...  Str = "52112"
I need to convert this string into an integer and the result should be like "0000052112". The result should be an integer. Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: You can leave it as string with extra `0`'s but you can't do that with an `int` `0000052112` is the same as `52112` to java they are both `52112`.

Comment: Agreeing with @brso05, "padding" is a term that makes only sense with `String`s. The `int` type represents numbers and numbers are independent of their representation.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you want to `parse` an `int` do manipulation then display with padding just `parse` it do you manipulation then convert it back to a string with padding and display...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot have an integer typed variable with leading zeros. You can pad the number with zeros but then it will become a String.

Take a look at:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad(java.lang.String,%20int)

In order to conform to the signature you have to convert the number to a string first, but that is no great deal.

Answer (score 1):

The leading zeroes have no meaning if the data type you require is an `Integer` (or any other numeric type). If on the other hand you need a `String` with leading zeroes, you can use this (works only if required string length is >= number of digits of the number you want to pad) :

```
String myNumber =  Integer.toString(42);
String myNumberWithLeadingZeroes = "0000000000" + myNumber; 
// 10 zeroes if you need a string of length 10 in the end
myNumberWithLeadingZeroes = myNumberWithLeadingZeroes.substring(myNumber.length());
```